# What's wrong with GetUserName Win32 API?

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm using GetUserName Win32 API to get the user name of my computer, but I found the user name is different (uppercase vs. lowercase only) when using my VPN connection into work when I was at home. I’m wondering if the VPN client or other software could be affecting the username?

Comment: Don't know if it matters, but just FYI:  Windows treats user names as case-insensitive.

Comment: We had a similar experience - on some systems the username was uppercase, on others - lowercase. We overcame the problem by unconditionally lowercasing the name this function returns - Windows treats it in case-insensitive manner anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The [GetUserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724432(VS.85).aspx#Mtps_DropDownFilterText) API states:

> Retrieves the name of the user
>   associated with the current thread.
>
> Use the GetUserNameEx function to
>   retrieve the user name in a specified
>   format. Additional information is
>   provided by the IADsADSystemInfo
>   interface.

So it looks like that GetUserName uses [IADsADSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa705962(VS.85).aspx) to get it's information.

If you look at the [IADsADSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa705962(VS.85).aspx) interface you see it has the method:

> get_UserName
>   Retrieves the Active
>   Directory distinguished name of the
>   current user, which is the logged-on
>   user or the user impersonated by the
>   calling thread.

So when your connected via VPN to a domain login you will most likely get Active Directory distinguished name of the current user and when you aren't, you most likely get the user name that you typed in (in whatever case you typed in) to log onto the computer with.

Comment: The user name is worng using IADsADSystemInfo to get it's information. The return user name is like this "EN=WYG,OU=XXX Address Lists,DC=apac,DC=XXX,DC=crop".

Answer (score 3):

This API returns the name as typed by the user when logging on to the computer. So if my username is 'esac', but I type 'Esac', this API will return 'Esac'. Subsequently if I type 'ESAC' that is what it will return as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but I suspect that GetUserName will end up talking to the DC when you're connected to your domain network, whereas it will use the local answer otherwise